# DataGridView jumps up on getting focus through code

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, focus

In my application i have a window form on which i shows a few links and a datagrid. On click of a link (Expand All), i shows all thhe rows in DataGridView. This makes the grid to jump up on screen. Its a very wierd behaviour. Please suggest some solution for same.

Thanks
Lalit

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that clicking 'Expand All' cause a postback... so to maintain page position try

Comment: hey drooksy, its winform app and not web. Anyways thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use scriptaculous and add effect to show the datagrid data.

Comment: What is that? Could you please elaborate it a bit?